# How to push new screen from global screen in blackberry?

Tags: blackberry

Here I am display push notification in globalscreen in blackberry, I need to push screen by clicking OK button of the dialog. I want to start app by clicking the ok button.

Please help me.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: will you help me in implementing push notification ?

Comment: @Signare Yes I implemnted notification and its came. but I on click dialog ok button not go on particular screen. Ok I will help you.

Comment: @Signare https://developer.blackberry.com/services/push use this link

Comment: Can you share some code?  Your description isn't completely clear.  Are you trying to push a **second** `Screen` from your global screen, after the global screen's **Ok** button is clicked?  And, when you say *"start app"*, do you mean you want your own app to come from the background to the foreground?

Comment: @Nate yes my app get push notification from background work and from background it shows globel screen dialog.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure I understand what you want, but if this doesn't work, just add a *comment* and I'll try to give you a better answer.

First, [read this on pushing global screens](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Properly-Push-and-Pop-Global-Screens/ta-p/445097)

and [this on performing actions after receiving global alerts](http://www.blackberry.com/knowledgecenterpublic/livelink.exe/fetch/2000/348583/800332/800505/800256/How_To_-_Have_Your_Application_Perform_an_Action_after_a_Global_Alert.html?nodeid=1287205&vernum=0)

Your code, if I'm understanding correctly, should be similar to the second link's example.

Then, if you implement the `DialogClosedListener`, like in the second link, you might have something like this:

**called from the background when you get notified:**

```java
Dialog myDialog = new Dialog(Dialog.D_OK_CANCEL, "Hello", Dialog.OK, null, 0);
myDialog.setDialogClosedListener(new MyListener());
UiApplication.getUiApplication().pushGlobalScreen(myDialog, 1, true);
```

**implementation of your dialog listener:**

```java
private class MyListener implements DialogClosedListener {

    public void dialogClosed(Dialog dialog, int choice) {
       switch (choice) {
          case Dialog.OK: 
              // ok clicked
              UiApplication.getUiApplication().requestForeground();
              break;
          case Dialog.CANCEL:
              // cancel clicked. or escape pressed
              break;
          default:
              break;
       }
   }
}
```

And, then in your `UiApplication` class, you can respond to activation, which will happen if the user selects **Ok** from the `Dialog`:

```java
public class MyApp extends UiApplication {
    private boolean _nextScreenShowing = false;
    public void activate() {
        super.activate();
        if (!_nextScreenShowing) {
            pushScreen(new NextScreen());
            _nextScreenShowing = true;
        }
    }
}
```

I show the `_nextScreenShowing` variable, just to make sure you think about whether pushing the next screen is appropriate.  It probably won't be **every** time `activate` is called.  You may need to keep track of that boolean flag by responding to the `Application.deactivate()` method, or maybe `Screen.onExposed()` or `Screen.onObscured()`.  All that depends on how your app works.